# Circle overlay multiplies below content

Tags: jquery, css

How do I get the circle to multiply the copy when hovered over? Realized background-blend-mode: multiply;  only affects the content inside the circle.

Goal is for the red circle to multiply the content below

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/80bLpt1c/)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
  var xp = 0, yp = 0;
   
  $(document).mousemove(function(e){
    mouseX = e.pageX - 30;
    mouseY = e.pageY - 30; 
  });
    
  setInterval(function(){
    xp += ((mouseX - xp)/6);
    yp += ((mouseY - yp)/6);
    $("#circle").css({left: xp +'px', top: yp +'px'});
  }, 20);

});
```

```css
body{
 position: relative;
 height: 100%; 
 width : 100%;  
 margin: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

h1{
 padding: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 z-index: 10;
 background-color: none;
 font-family: Helvetica;
 font-size: 100px;
}

.circle {
/* z-index: -10;*/
 position: absolute;
 background-blend-mode: multiply; 
 background-color: red;
 width: 200px; 
 height: 200px; 
  border-radius: 50%;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1> WORDS HERE </h1> 
<span id="circle" class="circle"></span>
```

Comment: I did something similar, but with a clip-mask. Check this link and try to reverse engineer it: https://repl.it/@Jodastt/ThistleTiredRay

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-blend-mode/ says that the multiply effect occurs relative to a background image and a background color, and you have no background image here.

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve, there is `mix-blend-mode` which applies to the backdrop https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode